# Error when using midasr package

Tags: r

Ive made a **Minimal Reproducible Example** for the problem i'm facing.

*Data for Y(monthly dependent variable):*

```
monthlytest <- c(-.035, 0.455)
ytest <- ts(monthlytest, start=c(2008,8), frequency=12)
```

*Data for X(daily explanatory variable):*

```
lol1 <- paste(2008, sprintf("%02s",rep(1:12, each=30)), sprintf("%02s", 1:30), sep="-") [211:270]
lol2 <- seq(0.015, 0.078, length.out=60)

xtest <- zoo(lol2, order.by = lol1)
```

*Load package:*

```
library(midasr)
library(zoo)
```

*Run regression:*

```
beta <- midas_r(ytest ~ mls(ytest, 1, 1) + mls(xtest, 3:30, 30))
```

When this final line of code is run I get this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
  Error in matrix(NA, nrow = n - nrow(X), ncol = ncol(X)) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (< 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is produced by the function `mls`:

```
> mls(xtest, 3:30, 30)
Erreur dans matrix(NA, nrow = n - nrow(X), ncol = ncol(X)) : 
  valeur 'nrow' incorrecte (< 0)
```

This happens because `mls` expects numeric argument. Converting `xtest` to numeric solves the problem:

```
xtn <- as.numeric(xtest)
beta <- midas_r(ytest ~ mls(ytest, 1, 1) + mls(xtn, 3:30, 30))
```

Which produces error again:

```
Erreur dans prepmidas_r(y, X, mt, Zenv, cl, args, start, Ofunction, user.gradient,  : 
  l'argument "start" est manquant, avec aucune valeur par défaut
```

Which means that you did not specify `start` which is mandatory for function `midas_r`. Your model is the unrestricted MIDAS model, which means that either you need to use function `midas_u` or supply `start=NULL`. But even this does not help:

```
> beta <- midas_r(ytest ~ mls(ytest, 1, 1) + mls(xtn, 3:30, 30),start=NULL)
Erreur dans midas_r.fit(prepmd) : 
  Not possible to estimate MIDAS model, more parameters than observations
```

You have two low frequency observations, which in theory allows you to estimate two parameters, your model has 29. So you need to have at least 30 low frequency observations (since you lose one observation due to lagged dependent variable) to estimate this model.

Comment: Thank you for addressing the remaining errors as well mpiktas! it has worked like a charm when I used my entire dataset!

Comment: mpiktas, unfortunately I have ran into another error and Ive described it the best I could in a seperate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165621/error-when-forecasting-with-midasr). Could you kindly have a look?

Comment: Hey mpiktas, my previous question was framed in an unhelpful way and I apologize, I have included a reproducible example in an edit to the [same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165621/error-when-forecasting-with-midasr-reproducible-example-included) if you could please have a look at it.