# Error when forecasting with midasr (reproducible example included)

Tags: r, forecasting

The code is self contained, except the datasets which is linked below.

**.csv files used in the code, download this first please:** https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#folders/0B1ciW4R5hjUCRFpjQlJKZGFqcVU

```
library(midasr)
library(zoo)


 yvellaregdata <- read.table("~/Desktop/attempt1/ymonthlyjackson.csv", quote="\"")
 yvellareg <- ts(yvellaregdata, start=c(2008,7), frequency=12)

 xvellareginit <- read.table("~/Desktop/attempt1/xdailyjackson.csv", quote="\"")
 xvellaregzoo <- zoo(xvellareg)
 xvellareg <- as.numeric(xvellaregzoo) #i had to convert to numeric for it to work

#yvellareg is the monthly y variable
#xvellareg is the daily x variable
 betareg <- midas_r(yvellareg ~ mls(yvellareg, 1, 1) + mls(xvellareg, 3:25, 30), start=NULL)
 summary(betareg)


#Defining data for forecasting
 xdailyfulldataread <- read.table("~/Desktop/attempt1/xdailyfulldatajackson.csv", quote="\"")
 xdailyfulldata <- zoo(xdailyfulldataread)
 xdailyfulldata <- as.numeric(xdailyfulldata)

 ymonthlyfulldataread <- read.table("~/Desktop/attempt1/ymonthlyfulldatajackson.csv", quote="\"")
 ymonthlyfulldata <- ts(ymonthlyfulldataread,start=c(2008,7), frequency=12)


fulldata <- list(xx=xdailyfulldata,
                   yy=ymonthlyfulldata)
insample <- 1:length(yvellareg)
outsample <- (1:length(fulldata$yy))[-insample]

#errorhere
avgf<-average_forecast(list(betareg),
                       data=fulldata,
                       insample=insample,
                       outsample=outsample)
sqrt(avgf$accuracy$individual$MSE.out.of.sample)
```

Comment: How do you construct `fulldata`? It should be a list with variables `yvellareg` and `xvellareg` as elements named appropriately. From what I see, the list has element named `yy`. So the regressors used in the model are not found in the data, hence the error message.

Comment: @mpiktas but in my case xvellareg and yvellareg are subsamples of xdailyfulldata and ydailyfulldata.  In the midasr user guide's first example for "forecasting GDP growth", a window was created for the regressor and another bigger window was used for constructing the full data. I wanted to have a similar effect in my case too.

Comment: If i had defined fulldata with a list containing variables yvellareg and xvellareg, will i not be estimating parameters and then forecasting on the same sample?

Comment: The function `average_forecast` requires full data. It reestimates the model using the insample data, and does the forecasting using outsample data.

Comment: You are likely to get a better response if you put the reproducible example here, and not on another web site.

Comment: @mpiktas I believe that is exactly what I have done here; everythings a bit more confusing compared to the examples in the user guide because i can't simply let both the y and x be timeseries objects, that would have been very nice and straightforward.

Comment: Try `names(fulldata)<c("xvellareg","yvellareg")` before `average_forecast`. Why can't you let the objects be times series objects?

Comment: @mpiktas the y variable is a ts() object, but the x variable can't be ts() because AFAIK, ts() does not work with daily data. I tried defining it as a ts object anyway in an unmeaningful way just to see if it works but it doesn't.
 
The 'names(fulldata)<c.....' doesnt seem to do anything, it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Yes because, you forgot to make xdaillyfulldata numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already prepared the data with in-sample and full-sample outside of R, there is no need to convert it to time series objects.

Here is the cleaned-up version of your code, which assumes that data files are in R working directory:

```
library(midasr)

yvellareg <- scan("ymonthlyjackson.csv")
xvellareg <- scan("xdailyjackson.csv")

#yvellareg is the monthly y variable
#xvellareg is the daily x variable
 betareg <- midas_r(yvellareg ~ mls(yvellareg, 1, 1) + mls(xvellareg, 3:25, 30), start=NULL)
 summary(betareg)


#Defining data for forecasting
xdailyfulldata <- scan("xdailyfulldatajackson.csv")
ymonthlyfulldata <- scan("ymonthlyfulldatajackson.csv")


fulldata <- list(xvellareg=xdailyfulldata,
                   yvellareg=ymonthlyfulldata)
insample <- 1:length(yvellareg)
outsample <- (1:length(fulldata$yvellareg))[-insample]

#errorhere
avgf<-average_forecast(list(betareg),
                       data=fulldata,
                       insample=insample,
                       outsample=outsample)
sqrt(avgf$accuracy$individual$MSE.out.of.sample)
```

But this still throws an error, since your data is not conformable. Package midasr expects that each low frequency period has the same number of high frequency periods. In your case this is 30. But we have

```
> length(xdailyfulldata)
[1] 1230
> length(ymonthlyfulldata)
[1] 42
> 1230/42
[1] 29.28571
```

Since `42*30=1260` it seems you have more monthly than daily observations. Dropping one monthly observation makes the code run without the errors:

```
fulldata <- list(xvellareg=xdailyfulldata,
                   yvellareg=ymonthlyfulldata[-42])
insample <- 1:length(yvellareg)
outsample <- (1:length(fulldata$yvellareg))[-insample]

#errorhere
avgf<-average_forecast(list(betareg),
                       data=fulldata,
                       insample=insample,
                       outsample=outsample)
sqrt(avgf$accuracy$individual$MSE.out.of.sample)
[1] 1.118709
```

Comment: this is perfect, thank you so much. I wish I knew about the scan() earlier! My model's residual s.e and the forecast's RMSE are way off so i've clearly overfit the data which is something Ive been expecting.  From looking at the plots of my x and y, I can guesstimate that a HF lag of 70-90~ has the most predictive power for y; however I only have 66 low frequency variables in my entire dataset. There is no way to allow mls() for the HF variable  to have a lag of more than 66 is there? Should i maybe manipulate my data to work around this? Is there anything else you can suggest? Thanks

Comment: There is no restriction on number of lags in `mls` function. The HF lag of 70-90 in your case corresponds to LF lag 2-3, so you can use it without any problems. However you cannot use LF lags larger than available LF observations, because you will exhaust all the degrees of freedom.

Comment: ah right that makes sense. thanks for the answer :D im going to mess around with all the other functions in the package now.

Comment: Cheers. You can post similar questions in midasr package issues page https://github.com/mpiktas/midasr/issues. This way I will get notified immediately. I suspect these types of questions are too specific for stackoverflow.